# IE Dev and Build Fails with nuxt JS as Object doesn't support property or method or Unable to set property 'overflow' of undefined or null reference

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer, nuxt.js, polyfills, babel-polyfill

Please let me know if you understand why my nuxt app fails on internet explorer.
In the part of my code, I had used array.includes() which I realized is not supported by IE and removed but still not working. I do use forEach loops which should be supported by IE11

Console Error :

```
[Vuetify] [UPGRADE] 'v-content' is deprecated, use 'v-main' instead.

found in

---> <VMain>
       <VApp>
         <Layouts/default.vue> at layouts/default.vue
           <Root>
TypeError: Unable to set property 'overflow' of undefined or null reference
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      description: "Unable to set property 'overflow' of undefined or null reference",
      message: "Unable to set property 'overflow' of undefined or null reference",
      name: "TypeError",
      number: -2146823281,
      stack: "TypeError: Unable to set property 'overflow' of undefined or null reference
   at setProp (eval code:7154:7)
   at updateStyle (eval code:7215:7)
   at invokeCreateHooks (eval code:6059:7)
   at createElm (eval code:5946:11)
   at createChildren (eval code:6043:9)
   at createElm (eval code:5944:9)
   at createChildren (eval code:6043:9)
   at createElm (eval code:5944:9)
   at createChildren (eval code:6043:9)
   at createElm (eval code:5944:9)",
      Symbol(Lang fallback)_i.cu2qu2ppg6q: undefined,
      Symbol(react.element)_h.cu2qu2ppg6q: undefined
   }

TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'values'
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      description: "Object doesn't support property or method 'values'",
      message: "Object doesn't support property or method 'values'",
      name: "TypeError",
      number: -2146827850,
      stack: "TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'values'
   at Application.prototype.update (eval code:40041:5)
   at Application.prototype.register (eval code:40031:5)
   at callUpdate (eval code:36617:9)
   at created (eval code:36603:7)
   at invokeWithErrorHandling (eval code:1853:5)
   at callHook (eval code:4213:7)
   at Vue.prototype._init (eval code:4998:5)
   at VueComponent (eval code:5144:7)
   at createComponentInstanceForVnode (eval code:3280:3)
   at init (eval code:3111:7)",
      Symbol(Lang fallback)_i.cu2qu2ppg6q: undefined,
      Symbol(react.element)_h.cu2qu2ppg6q: undefined
   }

TypeError: Unable to get property 'parentNode' of undefined or null reference
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      description: "Unable to get property 'parentNode' of undefined or null reference",
      message: "Unable to get property 'parentNode' of undefined or null reference",
      name: "TypeError",
      number: -2146823281,
      stack: "TypeError: Unable to get property 'parentNode' of undefined or null reference
   at parentNode (eval code:5711:3)
   at patch (eval code:6503:9)
   at Vue.prototype._update (eval code:3942:7)
   at updateComponent (eval code:4054:7)
   at get (eval code:4473:5)
   at run (eval code:4548:5)
   at flushSchedulerQueue (eval code:4304:5)
   at Anonymous function (eval code:1979:9)
   at flushCallbacks (eval code:1905:5)
   at run (eval code:75:13)",
      Symbol(Lang fallback)_i.cu2qu2ppg6q: undefined,
      Symbol(react.element)_h.cu2qu2ppg6q: undefined
   }
```

Nuxt Config:

```
export default {
  env: {
  
  },
  mode: 'spa',
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  router: {
    trailingSlash: undefined, scrollBehavior: function (to, from, savedPosition) {
      return { x: 0, y: 0 }
    }
  },
  redirect: [
    {
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      from: '(?!^\/$|^\/[?].*$)(.*\/[?](.*)$|.*\/$)',
      to: (from, req) => {
        const base = req._parsedUrl.pathname.replace(/\/$/, '');
        const search = req._parsedUrl.search;
        return base + (search != null ? search : '');
      }
    },
  ],
  head: {
    titleTemplate: '%s - ' + process.env.npm_package_name,
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        href:
          "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900"
      },
      {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        href:
          "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"
      },
      {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        href:
          "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css"
      },
      {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        href:
          "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/font-awesome@4.x/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      },
      {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        href:
          "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Architects+Daughter|PT+Serif&display=swap"
      },
      {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        href:
          "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons"
      },
      {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        href:
          "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Serif:400i&display=swap"
      },
      {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        href:
          "https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css"
      }

    ], script: [
  { src: 'https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?version=3.52.1&features=es5%2Ces6%2Ces7%2CArray.prototype.forEach%2CArray.prototype.includes%2CArray.prototype.values%2CString.prototype.includes' }
  
]
  },
  /*
  ** Customize the progress-bar color
  */
  loading: { color: '#fff' },
  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: ['~/assets/global.css'
  ],
  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/vue-json-viewer.js', mode: 'client' }, { src: '~/plugins/vueditor.js', mode: 'client' }
  ],
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
  */
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
  ],
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios', 'vue-scrollto/nuxt',
    '@nuxtjs/redirect-module','vue-scrollto/nuxt',
  ],
  /*
  ** Axios module configuration
  ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
  */
  axios: {
  },
  /*
  ** vuetify module configuration
  ** https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module
  */
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    theme: {
      dark: false,

    }
  },
  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {


    extend(config, ctx) {
    }
  }
}
```

Package.json:

```
    {
      "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.3.6",
    "@nuxtjs/redirect-module": "^0.3.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.12.2",
    "vue-json-viewer": "^2.2.11",
    "vue-quill-editor": "^3.0.6",
    "vue-scrollto": "^2.18.1",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@nuxt/**/terser": "3.14.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--Update
Maybe this will help someone in the future but if you have any polyfill issues where you can not use ES5/6/7 in IE11, and in NUXTJS:

GO to polyfill.io/v3/url-builder
then select the functions you need and get the link and put it in nuxt.config.js in this format:

```
    head:{
script: [
      { src: 'https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?version=3.52.1&features=es5%2Ces6%2Ces7%2CArray.prototype.forEach%2CArray.prototype.includes%2CArray.prototype.values%2CString.prototype.includes' }
    ]}
```

My issue regarding: Unable to set property 'overflow' of undefined or null reference
Traced back to a SVG file and the foreignObject tag.

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't support `forEach` for HTMLCollection.

You could add the following polyfill in your script to polyfill `forEach` then it can be used for both NodeList and HTMLCollection in IE:

```
//polyfill
var ctors = [typeof NodeList !== "undefined" && NodeList, typeof HTMLCollection !== "undefined" && HTMLCollection];
for (var n = 0; n < ctors.length; ++n) {
    var ctor = ctors[n];
    if (ctor && ctor.prototype && !ctor.prototype.forEach) {
        // (Yes, there's really no need for `Object.defineProperty` when doing the `forEach`)
        ctor.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
        if (typeof Symbol !== "undefined" && Symbol.iterator && !ctor.prototype[Symbol.iterator]) {
            Object.defineProperty(ctor.prototype, Symbol.iterator, {
                value: Array.prototype[Symbol.itereator],
                writable: true,
                configurable: true
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you reply. it made me look deeper into it and fix up 70% of my problems. Really appreciated.